# Still cannot access SoapHeader from endpoint

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-ws, soapheader

I am new to web services. After much googling and trying everything that's been posted about accessing the `SoapHeader` from endpoints, I still cannot get it to work. I'm getting the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint when adding
>   SoapHeader in the method signature of the handling method.

If I remove the `SoapHeader` parameter, I do not have any issues.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:sws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services
http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services/web-services-2.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="services" />
<sws:annotation-driven />

<sws:interceptors>
    <bean id="validatingInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadValidatingInterceptor">
        <property name="schema" value="/WEB-INF/schemas/cfPostBack2015.xsd" />
        <property name="validateRequest" value="true"/> 
        <property name="validateResponse" value="true"/> 
    </bean> 
    <bean id="loggingInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.interceptor.PayloadLoggingInterceptor" /> 
</sws:interceptors>

<sws:static-wsdl id="postBackService2015"
    location="/WEB-INF/schemas/postBackService2015.wsdl" />

<bean id="marshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xmlbeans.XmlBeansMarshaller" />
<bean id="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.method.MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor">
    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>  
    <constructor-arg ref="marshaller"/>  
</bean>

<bean id="defaultMethodEndpointAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.adapter.DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter">
    <property name="methodArgumentResolvers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="methodReturnValueHandlers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="marshallingPayloadMethodProcessor" />
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="postbackService"
    class="PostBackServiceImpl" />
<bean id="postBackEndpoint"
    class="PostBackEndpoint">
    <property name="postBackService" ref="postBackService" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

Endpoint class:

```
package endpoints;

import javax.annotation.Resource;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.PayloadRoot;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapHeader;

import PostBackService;
import cfPostBack.x2015.PostBackRequestDocument;
import cfPostBack.x2015.PostBackResponseDocument;

@Endpoint
public class PostBackServiceEndpoint {
    private static final String TARGET_NAMESPACE = 
        "http://services/cfPostBack/2015/";

    @Resource(name="postBackService")
    private PostBackService postBackService;

    @Autowired                                                                             
    public PostBackServiceEndpoint(PostBackService postBackService) {
        this.postBackService = postBackService;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(localPart = "postBackRequest", namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)
    @ResponsePayload
    public PostBackResponseDocument getPostBackResponse(
        @RequestPayload PostBackRequestDocument request, SoapHeader soapHeader) 
        throws Exception {

        PostBackResponseDocument response = 
            postBackService.processPostBackRequest(request);

        return response;
    }

    public void setPostBackService(PostBackService postBackService) {
        this.postBackService = postBackService;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to add a `org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.adapter.method.SoapMethodArgumentResolver` bean to the `methodArgumentResolvers` list.

Comment: Based on Spring Docs, MessageContext and SoapHeader, etc should be enabled by default. Anyhow, I tried adding a SoapMethodArgumentResolver bean to my methodArgumentRsolvers list. It still didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Andreas, you are right. Adding SoapMethodArgumentResolver bean to the methodArgumentResolvers list does work. I was trying to access the MessageContext in the endpoint instead of the SoapHeader. For the MessageContext, I added MessageContextMethodArgumentResolver.