# Spring-WS Server with MTOM and SoapHeaders

Tags: java, spring-boot, soap, spring-ws, mtom

I am trying to build a mock for an existing SOAP Service. The service has several methods that use both MTOM upload in form of `byte[]` and use SoapHeaders to submit the rest of the information. Moreover, the service uses SoapActions to identify endpoint actions. I can not modify the service. I generated the API Objects using *wsdl2java*

**Endpoint:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.Endpoint;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.RequestPayload;
import org.springframework.ws.server.endpoint.annotation.ResponsePayload;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapHeaderElement;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.annotation.SoapAction;
import org.springframework.ws.soap.server.endpoint.annotation.SoapHeader;

@Endpoint
@RequiredArgsConstructor(onConstructor = @__(@Autowired))
@Slf4j
public class RenderJobEndpoint {

...

    @SoapAction(value = NAMESPACE_URI + "CreateJob")
    @ResponsePayload
    public RenderJobInfo createJob(@RequestPayload RenderJobCreateJobData parameters,
        @SoapHeader("{http://www.someservice.com/serviceName/}"}fileName") SoapHeaderElement fileNameElement) {

            String fileName = fileNameElement.getText();    
            return service.doStuff(parameters, fileName);
        }

...
}
```

**XSD file**

```
<xs:element name="RenderJobCreateJobData">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="data" type="q3:StreamBody" 
                xmlns:q3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/Message" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="fileHash" nillable="true" type="xs:base64Binary" />
<xs:element name="fileName" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="fileOptions" nillable="true" type="xs:string" />
```

*fileHash*, *fileName*, *fileOptions* are headers. In my Mock I do not need all of them. I have tried adding them all to the method's signature but it changed nothing.

**WebServiceConfig**

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurationSupport {

    // ********************************   MTOM   ***********************************************

    @Bean
    @Override
    public DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter defaultMethodEndpointAdapter() {
        List<MethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<>();
        argumentResolvers.add(soapMethodArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(methodProcessor());

        List<MethodReturnValueHandler> returnValueHandlers = new ArrayList<>();
        returnValueHandlers.add(methodProcessor());

        DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter adapter = new DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter();
        adapter.setMethodArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        adapter.setMethodReturnValueHandlers(returnValueHandlers);


        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public SoapMethodArgumentResolver soapMethodArgumentResolver() {
        return new SoapMethodArgumentResolver();
    }

    @Bean
    public MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor() {
        return new MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor(marshaller());
    }


    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller jaxb2Marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        jaxb2Marshaller.setContextPath("com.mockservice.service.apidata");
        jaxb2Marshaller.setMtomEnabled(true);
        jaxb2Marshaller.setProcessExternalEntities(true);

        return jaxb2Marshaller;
    }

    // ********************************   MTOM END  ***********************************************


    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean<>(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "RenderEngine")
    public Wsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition() {
        SimpleWsdl11Definition simpleWsdl11Definition = new SimpleWsdl11Definition();
        simpleWsdl11Definition.setWsdl(new ClassPathResource("someFile.wsdl"));
        return simpleWsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public CommonsXsdSchemaCollection xsdSchemaCollection() {
        return new CommonsXsdSchemaCollection(
                new ClassPathResource("someFile.xsd"));
    }

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(final List<EndpointInterceptor> interceptors) {
        interceptors.add(new MockEndpointInterceptor());
    }
}
```

I followed the official Spring docs to allow for MTOM handling and overridden the *DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter*. I passed a Marshaller with MTOM enabled. I've [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25980487/still-cannot-access-soapheader-from-endpoint) that in order to allow for SoapHeaders one should also use *SoapMethodArgumentResolver*, so I did.

My endpoints do not work with both MTOM and SoapHeaders. When I remove SoapHeaders from the endpoint method, the endpoint works, payload is correct but headers are ignored. When I do not override *DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter* SoapHeaders work, but MTOM payload is 0 bytes.

When I leave the code as it is, the following happens:

- SoapMessageDispatcher | Endpoint mapping ... maps request to endpoint ... (finds an endpoint)
- SoapMessageDispatcher | Testing endpoint adapter (fails)
- throws java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint

Any clues on how to solve it?

**Versions**

- spring-boot-starter-web-services: 2.2.4.RELEASE

Answer (score -1):

I've solved this same issue by adding another Method Argument Resolver. Here's the working solution

```
@Bean
DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter defaultMethodEndpointAdapter(MarshallingPayloadMethodProcessor methodProcessor) {

        DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter adapter = new DefaultMethodEndpointAdapter();
        
        List<MethodArgumentResolver> argumentResolvers = new ArrayList<>();
        argumentResolvers.add(soapHeaderElementMethodArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(soapMethodArgumentResolver());
        argumentResolvers.add(methodProcessor);
        
        adapter.setMethodArgumentResolvers(argumentResolvers);
        adapter.setMethodReturnValueHandlers(Collections.singletonList(methodProcessor));
        return adapter;
    }
```